# CMake warning has occurred

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I am a ROS beginner. I am doing SLAM of turtlebot 3 (waffle) in the ubuntu 16.04, ros (kinetic) personal computer environment.I downloaded and built https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation.git to install the costmap _ 2 d package. Then, such an error came out.What should I do?

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "tf2_sensor_msgs"
  with any of the following names:

    tf2_sensor_msgsConfig.cmake
    tf2_sensor_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "tf2_sensor_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "tf2_sensor_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
  If "tf2_sensor_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
  sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  navigation/costmap_2d/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'tf2_sensor_msgs'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "tf2_sensor_msgs"
  with any of the following names:

    tf2_sensor_msgsConfig.cmake
    tf2_sensor_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "tf2_sensor_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "tf2_sensor_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
  If "tf2_sensor_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
  sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  navigation/costmap_2d/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305640/cmake-warning-has-occurred./) by [saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/37890/saito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2018-10-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are already some questions about this issue : [#q138236](https://answers.ros.org/question/138236/catkin_make-cmake-error/), [#q305359](https://answers.ros.org/question/305359/cmake_error-gazebo_ros/#305360) for exemple.

It's just that you haven't installed the package `tf2_sensor_msgs` :

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-tf2-sensor-msgs
```

It should solve your issue.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/37890/saito/) on 2018-10-13**:
thank you!!

**Comment by [dvc97](https://answers.ros.org/users/39410/dvc97/) on 2019-01-10**:
It should be :
`sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-tf2-sensor-msgs`

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-01-11**:
Yes, typo fixed.

**Comment by [meng100](https://answers.ros.org/users/67304/meng100/) on 2021-06-10**:
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-tf2-sensor-msgs